# tslib not creating device

Tags: linux, embedded, arm

I am trying to embed tslib on an ARM system, in order to use a touchscreen device ; I already installed it successfully but unfortunately I can't retrieve all my notes to do it again. x)

I cross-compiled the libraries files, and I put them into */usr/lib* ; I have created the conf file */etc/ts.conf* and I have exported the good environment variables :

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE="/dev/event2"
export TSLIB_CONFFILE="/etc/ts.conf"
```

Here is my problem : tslib doesn't seem to create the event device when I plug the device in. And here is the result of *ts_calibrate* : `ts_open: No such file or directory`

I think it tries to open */dev/event2* which doesn't exist because it has not been created by tslib.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What kind of kernel + userspace do you have ? device file creation is usually
the job of kernel hotplug + udev or mdev.

In any case, tslib is not supposed to create device file. You have two options :

- creating the device manually, provided your busybox contains the mknod utility :

  ```
  mknod event2 c 13 66
  ```

  where 66 is the minor number, it should be one more than the minor number for event1.
- launching mdev -s and see if the content of your /dev directory change
- find out why the vent device is not detected / created : please post the output of `uname -a`, and `dmesg` after boot.

Comment: We have a specific kernel based on Debian (and we use Busybox) but we patched a lot of things. In /dev I already have 2 devices, event0 and event1 ; the touchscreen is supposed to be /dev/event2. The touchscreen is detected 'cause the framebuffer lib is working. ;)

Comment: I add "usbtouchscreen" module, that contains the eGalax driver ; now, dmesg give me that : `<6>input: eGalax Inc. USB TouchController as /devices/platform/str8100-ehci/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3.3/1-1.3.3:1.0/input/input2` but I still can't see how to get the inputs :/

Comment: try mdev -s after installing the module

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to `mknod` the `/dev/event2` yourself? Are you positive your library makes the device node?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `mknod` is not available on our busybox. Nothing changed when launching `mdev -s`, I already tryed that. :/
Here is the result of uname : `Linux MYNAME 2.6.24.4 #3 Fri Dec 2 16:54:41 CET 2011 armv4l unknown` (MYNAME is just the system name, I replaced it for privacy reason ;) )

And `dmesg` :

```
<6>usb 1-1.3: new high speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 23
<6>usb 1-1.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
<6>hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
<6>hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
<6>usb 1-1.3.2: new high speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 24
<6>usb 1-1.3.2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
<6>udlfb: DisplayLink AT-7 - serial #200694
<6>udlfb: vid_17e9&pid_02fc&rev_0104 driver's dlfb_data struct at c1031000
<6>udlfb: console enable=0
<6>udlfb: fb_defio enable=0
<6>udlfb: vendor descriptor length:23 data:23 5f 01 0021 00 04 04 07 00 01
<4>udlfb: DL chip limited to 1500000 pixel modes
<4>dlfb_alloc_urb_list
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : INIT_DELAYED_WORK dlfb_release_urb_work
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : after INIT_DELAYED_WORK
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb end
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : INIT_DELAYED_WORK dlfb_release_urb_work
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : after INIT_DELAYED_WORK
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb end
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : INIT_DELAYED_WORK dlfb_release_urb_work
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : after INIT_DELAYED_WORK
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb end
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : INIT_DELAYED_WORK dlfb_release_urb_work
<4>dlfb_release_urb_work : after INIT_DELAYED_WORK
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb
<4>usb_fill_bulk_urb end
<4>dlb_alloc_urb_list : before sema_init
<4>dlb_alloc_urb_list : after sema_init
<5>udlfb: allocated 4 65024 byte urbs
<4>dlfb_setup_modes
<4>dlfb_get_edid
<4>dlfb_is_valid_mode
<6>udlfb: 800x480 valid mode
<4>udlfb: Reallocating framebuffer. Addresses will change!
<4>dlfb_ops_check_var
<4>dlfb_is_valid_mode
<6>udlfb: 800x480 valid mode
<5>udlfb: set_par mode 800x480
<4>dlfb_set_video_mode
<4>dlfb_get_urb end
<4>dlfb_set_vid_cmds
<4>dlfb_submit_urb
<4>dlfb_submit_urb : after usb_submit_urb ret=0
<4>dlfb_set_video_mode end
<4>dlfb_urb_completion
<4>up release_urb_work !!!
<4>dlfb_urb_completion end
<4>dlfb_handle_damage
<4>dlfb_get_urb end
<4>dlfb_submit_urb
<4>dlfb_submit_urb : after usb_submit_urb ret=0
<6>udlfb: DisplayLink USB device /dev/fb1 attached. 800x480 resolution. Using 1504K framebuffer memory
<4>dlfb_urb_completion
<4>up release_urb_work !!!
<4>dlfb_urb_completion end
<6>usb 1-1.3.3: new full speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 25
<3>usb 1-1.3.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
<3>usb 1-1.3.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
<6>usb 1-1.3.3: new full speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 26
<3>usb 1-1.3.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
<3>usb 1-1.3.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
<6>usb 1-1.3.3: new full speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 27
<3>usb 1-1.3.3: device not accepting address 27, error -32
<6>usb 1-1.3.3: new full speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 28
<3>usb 1-1.3.3: device not accepting address 28, error -32
<6>usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, address 23
<6>usb 1-1.3.2: USB disconnect, address 24
<6>udlfb: USB disconnect starting
<4>dlfb_free_framebuffer_work
<4>udlfb: fb_info for /dev/fb1 has been freed
<4>dlfb_free
<5>udlfb: Waiting for completes and freeing all render urbs
<4>udlfb: freeing dlfb_data c1031000
<6>usb 1-1: USB disconnect, address 12
<6>usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using str8100-ehci and address 29
<6>usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
<6>hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
<6>hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

Answer (score 0):

`tslib` doesn't create an input device; your touchscreen's device driver does. `tslib` uses it and you can call `ts_read()` to get filtered samples. There are X11 and Qt5 wrappers that do this. That's the way it always was.

As of version 1.3 of `tslib`, there is `tslib/tools/ts_uinput` that you can use to create an input device to point your environment to, see [tslib's project page](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib).

As of now, there is `tslib-1.3-rc1` if you want to test this.