# ts_calibrate fails to run from systemd script

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I have a script which is run by systemd on startup. It runs my application, if the user quits the application the script runs ts_calibrate and, when that's done it runs my app again. Worked fine in Angstrom but not on the Beaglebone Black running Debian.

**My mita.sh script**

```
while [ 1 ]; do
        if [ -e /etc/pointercal ]; then
                echo "Pointercal exists"
                ./mita6 -platform linuxfb -plugin evdevtouch:/dev/input/event1
                echo "Quit mita6"
        else
                echo "No pointercal"
                ts_calibrate
                echo "Quit ts_calibrate"
                ./mita6 -platform linuxfb -plugin evdevtouch:/dev/input/event1
        fi
echo "Calibrating..."
ts_calibrate
echo "Calibration Done."
sleep 2
done
```

When the system boots now, my app starts OK but when I exit the app ts_calibrate fails to run. I get the following error:-

> ts_open: No such file or directory

If I login in as root, then I can run the script from the command line and everything works as expected.
If, from the command line I enter `sudo ts_calibrate` then I get the same error.
Can someone help me understand whats going on here?
I can run the script successfully if I ssh in as root but if I then sudo, I don't seem to have the privileges for to run ts_calibrate! systemd also does not seem to have the correct privileges!

Regards,
James.

.
.
.
 **The systemd service**

```
#!/bin/sh -

[Unit]
Description=My Script

[Service]
USER=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/root
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'source /etc/profile ; /home/root/mita.sh'
After=dropbear.service
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

.
uname -a
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone67 #1 SMP Wed Sep 24 21:30:03 UTC 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Might this be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397680/tslib-not-creating-device ?

Comment: @pjz I think its different because the script works from the command line but not when run by the systemd service.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables were not passed, it seems, when ts_calibrate was executed so I had to make sure they were set and passed.
The final **working** script looks like this:-

```
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event1

while [ 1 ]; do
        if [ -e /etc/pointercal ]; then
                echo "Pointercal exists"
                /home/root/mita6 -platform linuxfb -plugin evdevtouch:/dev/input/event1
                echo "Quit mita6"
        else
                echo "No pointercal"
                killall mita6
                sudo -E /usr/bin/ts_calibrate
                echo "Quit ts_calibrate"
                /home/root/mita6 -platform linuxfb -plugin evdevtouch:/dev/input/event1
        fi
echo "Calibrating..."
killall mita6
sudo -E /usr/bin/ts_calibrate
echo "Calibration Done."
sleep 2
done
```